# capture post-mix audio buffer being sent from remoteiounit to speaker

Tags: ios, core-audio

Is there a way to capture the audio buffers that are being sent out of a remoteIOUnit to the speaker?  I am rendering a couple of different loops on different threads to the same IOUnit ( one is a click, the other has music ), and would like to perform analysis on how the music is lining up with the click without having to filter out any noise coming from, say, using the microphone input.  My math must be very accurate ( error less then 2ms ), so getting this post-mix buffer would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just add a render notify callback to the remoteIO with `AudioUnitAddRenderNotify`. You will then get four callbacks per buffer: input pre-render, input post-render, output pre-render, and output post-render. You just need to act on the appropriate ioActionFlags and inBusNumber.

```
AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(remoteIO, inputOutputTap, (__bridge void *)self);

OSStatus inputOutputTap (void *                         inRefCon,
                         AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *   ioActionFlags,
                         const AudioTimeStamp *         inTimeStamp,
                         UInt32                         inBusNumber,
                         UInt32                         inNumberFrames,
                         AudioBufferList *              ioData) {

    if (*ioActionFlags == kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender && inBusNumber == 0) {
        MyObject *self = (__bridge MyObject *)inRefCon;
        MyObjectDoTheThing(self,ioData,inTimeStamp); 
    }
    return noErr;
}
```